# Multiple selections without using shift

Tags: accessibility

In tutorials I've seen people doing multiple edge selections using the shift key (fairly standard way these days), but I am currently disabled in my left hand
(due to a stroke.
Is there a way to enter selection mode as a toggle, since I cannot click and hold shift at the same time. I have a MacBook Pro plus Wacom tablet.
a
Thanks  / Patric

Comment: There was a simple solution. I changed the mapping of the lower button on the pen to modifier shift, instead of right-click.